# Removing # values from URL Worpdress

Tags: wordpress

I have set permalinks properly in WordPress but getting urls like this

http://morevoucher.com/store/weight-watchers/#.U04Cf_mSxR8

How i can remove **#.U04Cf_mSxR8** this value

Comment: That really depends what's generating the anchor.  I'd look at my plugins if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

This code is generated by the addthis widget i n order to Track the URLs of your website.. You simply have to Remove #pubid= from the addthis_widget.js#pubid= on the Addthis share script you use on the Header.

Goodluck